# How to create an object which runat server asp

Tags: c#, asp.net

I wish to define a timer, however, the timer which define in my asp.net behind code doesn't work.

When I create the timer in the html, which enable runat server is running perfectly.

How I can define a timer on the behind code, with the runat = "server" attribute?

```
    private Timer loopMessage = new Timer();

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        loopMessage.Tick += new EventHandler<EventArgs>(loopMessage_Tick);
        loopMessage.Interval = 3000;
        loopMessage.Enabled = true;
    }
```

This code doesn't work, the event is not able to execute

Comment: Define "doesn't work".  We can't tell you what's wrong with code you're not showing us or problems you're not describing to us.  Also, *all* server-side code runs server-side.  You don't have to *specify* your C# code to run on the server.

Comment: What you want to do when timer elapsed? or do you want to try to make a timer in javascript??

Comment: @RyanShine: `Timer.Tick`?  Specifically which `Timer` class is this?  Also, background tasks in a web app might not be what you actually want.  What's the overall goal here?

Comment: I want to doing a real time web page

Comment: and I also mentioned, this is asp.net timer class, it doesn't contain a method named as Elapsed, in case , I only able to use tick

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386404.aspx

Comment: people still use update panels?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never added the `Timer` to the page.

It's created at the class level, but the class is disposed immediately upon handling the HTTP request and no server-side state is maintained for it.  So every request is essentially creating a `Timer` and then disposing it.

If `Timer` is indeed a page control, it would need to be added to the page.  I'm not entirely familiar with this control, but if it needs to emit JavaScript to the client in order to invoke things at given intervals then the control would need to be on the page to make that happen.

Something like this, perhaps:

```
this.Controls.Add(loopMessage);
```

Answer (score 0):

Like David said, this code actually creates a new timer on every postback. And if your timer is not in an update panel, then every tick triggers another postback. So if I understand your problem correctly, first you must add an update panel on your page, then maybe you can add that update panel's controls to this timer.

Or you can leave all that ASP.NET problems here and turn to javascript timer and use jquery ajax method to solve your problem. Be sure that this will be way more effective for this problem and your future projects.